# How to install Ubuntu QML Toolkit on 10.04

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

It is exactly what the title says.  I am trying to follow the instructions on the main portion of ubuntu's [app developer page](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/), but something is not working for me.  Is it because it is not supported under 10.04?  Any help is much appreciated.

Justin

Comment: It would be nice if you provided some more info. Like, **what** doesn't work for you? Any error messages? Be as thorough as you can be.

Comment: Timo,

Like I said in my first post, I put in the code that it told me to, and these are the errors I received:


Err http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main Packages
  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-beta1/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ui-toolkit/ppa/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that ui-toolkit has been built only for quantal as you can see in the package details page https://launchpad.net/~ui-toolkit/+archive/ppa/+packages